# What file structure should one follow if a lot of files are to be downloaded in android app?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am working on an android app and using ionic framework to build it. The application requires a lot of media files to be downloaded on the phone. These files can be categorized as *images, videos or sounds*. Right now I am saving the with their file type concatenated with the file name

eg. image-boy.png, sound-boy.png and so on

Such that all the files are in the same directory.

The average file size should be 0.2 Mb and the total number of files any user can download is around **3500**.

Should I use a different **file structure** like saving different file types in different directories (which I think, is generally followed) ?
What difference can it have on the **performance** of the app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally feel the doing separated files would work like a charm. The performance depends how u are loading them like if you load them in background then it is not an issue but if u load in foreground and the file is big then the user not be happy because he needs to wait until the loading is not over.

PROS:

Well structured files

CONS:

Need to look at too many folders while making small changes

PROS:

One folder to all.
Easy to maintain.

CONS:

Too complicated.
Doesnot know what type of file belongs to what segment of code(if not named correctly)

Tip out of scope: 0.2Mb is bit too big for images, try to reduce using tinypng kind of tool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This leads me to one more question. Does Cordova File transfer plugin [link](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) creates a directory if it does not exist? For eg. If I Download a file to `cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'media/images/' + <my_file_name.extension>` will it create a `media/images/` directory inside  `cordova.file.dataDirectory`

Comment: Yes, btw cordova.file.datadirectory is probably a section of `data` folder associated to ur application. Thus, it will create a folder called media/images under ur application package name. It is usually something like this `data/com.app.subapp/media/images/`

Comment: Do accept the answer if that solves ur query,  That will help others finding soln of same kind.